# Why $V_{\mathbb{C}} = V_{1,0}\oplus V_{0,1}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-geometry

I am having a little problem with elementary linear algebra.
Let $V$ being a real vector space. Lets call $V_{\mathbb{C}} := V\otimes \mathbb{C}$.
Consider $J: V \to V$ an automorphism such that $J^2 = - Id$.

We can extend $J$ to $V_{\mathbb{C}}$ as follows:
$J(v\otimes z) := J(v)\otimes z,$ for $v \in V, z \in \mathbb{C}$.

I know that the minimal polinomial for $J_{\mathbb{C}}$ has to be $p(x) = (x - i)(x+i)$, because ncessarily $J_{\mathbb{C}}$ has the same matrix over $V_{\mathbb{C}}$ of $J$ over $V$, once one basis for $V_{\mathbb{c}}$ is given by $\{v_i\otimes 1\}$ if $\{v_i\}$ is a basis for $V$.

But then, my question is, why can I assert that:

$$V_{\mathbb{C}} = V_{1,0}\oplus V_{0,1}?$$

where $V_{1,0} := \ker\{ J_{\mathbb{C}} - i\cdot Id\}$ and $V_{0,1} := \ker\{ J_{\mathbb{C}} + i\cdot Id\}?$

Comment: yes, I am sorry, I will correct. Thanks!

Comment: Anyway, are you familiar with the decomposition of a function $\Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ into odd and even parts?

Comment: Note that $\mathbb C/\mathbb R$ is a finite Galois extension. A very general framework for this is [Galois descent](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/galoistheory/galoisdescent.pdf).

Comment: @Travis, yes, I am.

Comment: @Frank, after having taught for almost two decades, one of the things I've concluded is that trying to explain simple things in terms of more complicated ones is seldom helpful, specially when one is not very specific (the «this is in Euler's works somewhere» phenomenon)

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez Sorry, I'm not mature enough to judge math, but the first time I learnt these linear algebra on the complex geometry class (text: Huybretch's introduction), I felt that the manipulation of tensors is quite messy, and appearance of some constants was quite annoying. My intuition was that we can do everything properly for a general Galois extension instead of $\mathbb C/\mathbb R$. After class, I did them on my own. I got into a theory where I didn't know how to advance. Recently, I discovered Galois descent and I realized that it was what I wanted.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez And I should clarify that I was an undergrad, and abstract algebra (including Galois theory) was taught before complex geometry, and it seemed to me natural to study general Galois extensions, and the decomposition is in fact in accordance to the action of Galois group, and it now seems to me that the introduction of $\otimes_\mathbb R\mathbb C$ shares the same motivation with Galois descent, not as random as «this is in Euler's works somewhere».

Comment: You pointed to a 19 page essay on descent in a question clearly motivated by complex structures, probably arising from differential geometry. That note is very relevant to the question, but in what way it is relevant is probably extremely opaque to anyone who did not already know this — unless you explain. And your comment, quite contrary to that, has great chances of mystifying the question. It would certainly be interesting for someone to write an answer in the spirit of descent, that helps people see the connection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've already computed the minimal polynomial.  It then suffices to note that a linear transformation is diagonalizable whenever [its minimal polynomial factors completely into distinct linear factors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_polynomial_(linear_algebra)#Applications).

Comment: Thank you! It's very obvious. Once $J$ is an automorphism and diagonalizable, we can decompose the space as the sums $J - \lambda Id$.

Comment: You're welcome.